# "Anything could happen" vs "anything can happen"

Tags: grammar

What's the difference betwee the following two sentences?

1- "Do not try to do this stunt. Anything ***could*** happen. You ***may/might/could*** get injured or die."

2- "Do not try to do this stunt. Anything ***can*** happen. You ***can*** get injured or die."

Comment: Functionally, there is no difference. Both express a warning of possible consequences. But *may/might/could* are less direct and a bit more understated.

Comment: @Robusto Thank you.As you have stayed "can" "could" both be used, can I say "you can/could get injured or die."?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.